# Why this python code is not scraping anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape images based on the search result from bing. But its not working. Here is my code:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

v = 0
s = input("Search: ")
p = {"q": s}
r = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/images/search", params=p)
print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
items = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "iusc"})

for item in items:
    img_obj = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
    img.save("./images/"+v,img.format)
    v += 1
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Please include some more information... are you getting an error? If not, at what point is the code not acting like you expect? What is `r.status_code`? Does `r.text` show the type of content you would expect? What is the content of `items`?

Comment: My aim is to download images based on search. It runs but can't download any image.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this:

```
items = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "thumb"})
for item in items:
    img_obj = requests.get(item["href"])
    if img_obj.ok:
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
        img.save("./images/" + str(v) + '.' + img.format, img.format)
        v += 1
    else:
        print(img_obj.status_code)
```

There are some problems in your code

Comment: Thanks! But it can't download the image...:(